# Rally API: How to print or export to pdf from Custom HTML

Tags: pdf, rally

I have created table with data using "custom html app".
I want now print this page but when I try to do it, it cuts few last columns.

I have tried to set style of body to "width:1000px" and then it prints ok but then it doesn't shows on whole screen and I have table of size 1000px

Answer (score 0):

We usually end up having slightly different css for printing than runtime.
Try this:

```
@media print {
    body {
        width: 1000px;
    }
}
```

Comment: It works for all elements on page except table. I still get table in size of screen.  I found I can print in correct way under firefox (but only portrait) when i select scaling.